# Complement a DNA sequence in Java

Tags: java

//I trying to solve a problem I got from Codewars
// The question is as follows
/*Deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) is a chemical found in the nucleus of cells and carries the "instructions" for the development and functioning of living organisms.

If you want to know more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA

In DNA strings, symbols "A" and "T" are complements of each other, as "C" and "G". You have function with one side of the DNA (string, except for Haskell); you need to get the other complementary side. DNA strand is never empty or there is no DNA at all (again, except for Haskell).
*/

```
    public class DnaStrand {

        public static String makeComplement(String dna) {
             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

             for(int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
                  char c = dna.charAt(i);
                  if(dna.charAt(i) == 'T'){
                      builder.append('A');
                  }
                  if(dna.charAt(i) == 'A'){
                      builder.append('T');
                  }
                  if(dna.charAt(i) == 'C'){
                      builder.append('G');
                  }
                  if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
                      builder.append('T');
                  }   
             }
             return builder.toString();
        }
    }
```

//This method seems to work correct
//But when I submit it, It shows that it is incorrect for various inputs from //code wars

Comment: Could you provide the inputs / expected outputs that it fails on?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please format your code and provide the error messages, the input you use, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Interesting, could you provide examples of "what" is incorrect according to codewar's correction ? Also we are in Java, you could create a simple string instead of a builder and append the correct character between quotes directly to it. Using a builder is "cleaner" but seems a bit like overkill ? Anyway it's just me being picky

Comment: Didn't you mix up G and C in terms of complements? In your last if statement I mean, As has also been pointed out in the answer

Comment: Flagged as offtopic, as this was a simple typographical error.

Comment: assertEquals("TTTT", DnaStrand.makeComplement("AAAA")); assertEquals("TAACG", DnaStrand.makeComplement("ATTGC"));assertEquals("CATA", DnaStrand.makeComplement("GTAT"));

Comment: You can do this more efficiently either by pre-sizing the `StringBuilder` (e.g. `new StringBuilder(dna.length())`), or by using `dna.toCharArray()` and rewriting the array elements.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is...

```
    if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
        builder.append('T');
    }
```

The complement of 'G' is 'C' (not 'T'). So it should be...

```
    if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
        builder.append('C');
    }
```

Comment: Noted, Thank you